# Add a subview from within and below another subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uiimageview

In an iOS app, I am adding a subview to my main view with:

```
[self.view addSubview:firstUIImageSubview];
```

However in the subview class firstUIImageSubview, I am creating and adding another subView (secondUIImageSubview) that I would like to put below the first subview with:

```
[self insertSubview:secondUIImageSubview belowSubview:self];
```

My problem is that the second subview is displayed above the first subview when I want to have it below. How is it possible to achieve that ? Thanks.

Comment: What does your question have to do with Cocoa?

Comment: It's Objective-C/Cocoa code for iOS dev.

Comment: I suggest you find out what Cocoa is before you use that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
[self.superview insertSubview:secondUIImageSubview atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use insertSubview:belowSubview: it places the subview in regards to other subviews that particular object manages.

`[self insertSubview:secondUIImageSubview belowSubview:self];`

Doesn't make much sense. Although self is a UIView (or a subclass) it still should never manage itself as a subview. Therefore

```
[self insertSubview:secondUIImageSubview belowSubview:firstUIImageSubview];
```

is probably what you want. But remember this will only place the secondUIImageSubview below firstUIImageSubview in terms of its Z-Index (it's depth on the screen). If you want it to be physically placed below firstUIImageSubview (IE it's XY coordinate) then you need to set it's position using subview's frame or setting its origin instead (by manipulating it's center or anchor points for instance).

Comment: Thanks. What I meant by below is in terms of z-index. But in your suggestion, how can I find 'firstUIImageSubview' knowing that it this piece of code is inside the firstUIImageSubview class ?

Comment: That piece of code should only be in firstUIImageSubview, if you want secondUIImageSubview to be managed by the first. In that case the depth shouldn't really matter because second is a part of first. It sounds like you intend to have both subviews managed by a view controller (after all that's why its there). The ViewController will have a reference to both subviews, and you can set your depth that way.

Comment: @LaurentCrivello and while BayPhillip's solution does work. It gives you no actual control over the depth. I would recommend doing [self.superview insertSubview:secondUIImageSubview belowSubview:self] if you insist on keeping the design the way it is, but I would HIGHLY recommend rethinking your design and getting a better idea of how view hierarchy and object oriented design should actually work. This will save you a lot of trouble later on.

Comment: I agree with @Literphor. A view in a UIVIewController shouldn't be managing another view in the UIViewController. Leave that logic in the actual controller.